# Meteor.js error: Exception from sub xGHk6PkFTQ9uv8ncg TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

I'm suddenly getting the following error

```
 Exception from sub xGHk6PkFTQ9uv8ncg TypeError: Cannot call method 'find' of undefined
     at null._handler (app/server/publications.js:6:22)
     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1349)
     at _.extend._runHandler (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:796)
     at _.extend._startSubscription (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:690)
     at _.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:508)
     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:472
```

The code around line 6 of `publications.js` is:

```
Meteor.publish('users', function() {
    return Meteor.users.find( {}, {fields:{'age': 1}} )
});
```

Why is this causing the error, and how can we resolve this?

Comment: Are you using some smart packages that hook or modify the default users collection? If so, can you list them?

Comment: Found out that `accounts-password` was suddenly missing, causing tis problem.

Comment: could you please mark as -self answered?-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that `accounts-password` was suddenly missing, causing this problem.